# Easy used head-only timer in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks

This timer can add tasks running for one-shot, several times, or loop every time and delete task by marking its id. It's simply implemented by a priority queue.

My purpose is easy to use and implement, thread safety, and not many errors.

How can I find out bad place and improve this code?

**timer.h**

```
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <future>

namespace easy {
typedef std::function<void()>                               callback_type;
typedef std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>  time_type;
typedef std::chrono::duration<int, std::milli>              msec_type;
struct timer_event
{
    timer_event(int id, const callback_type & callback, const time_type & when, const msec_type & duration = msec_type(0),
        bool loop = false)
        : callback(callback), when(when), duration(duration), loop(loop), id(id)
    {}
    timer_event(const timer_event & other)
        : callback(other.callback), when(other.when), duration(other.duration), loop(other.loop), id(other.id)
    {}
    timer_event(timer_event && other)
        : callback(other.callback), when(other.when), duration(other.duration), loop(other.loop), id(other.id)
    {}
    timer_event & operator=(timer_event && other)
    {
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }
    ~timer_event() {}
    timer_event & next() { when += duration; return *this; }
    void operator()() const { callback(); }
    void swap(timer_event & other)
    {
        std::swap(callback, other.callback);
        std::swap(when, other.when);
        std::swap(duration, other.duration);
        std::swap(loop, other.loop);
        std::swap(id, other.id);
    }
    callback_type   callback;
    time_type       when;
    msec_type       duration;
    bool            loop;
    int             id;
};

struct event_less : public std::less<timer_event>
{
    bool operator()(const timer_event &e1, const timer_event &e2) const
    {
        return (e2.when < e1.when);
    }
};

class Timer
{
    std::priority_queue<timer_event, std::vector<timer_event>, event_less>  event_queue;
    std::unique_ptr<std::thread>            handler;
    std::atomic<bool>                       _stop;
    std::atomic<int>                        taskid{ 0 };
    std::map<int, bool>                     invalid;
public:
    Timer()
    {
        handler = std::make_unique<std::thread>([this]()
        {
            using namespace std::chrono;
            auto start = system_clock::now();

            while (!_stop)
            {
                time_type now = system_clock::now();

                while (!event_queue.empty() &&
                    (event_queue.top().when < now))
                {
                    auto evt = std::move(event_queue.top());

                    if (!invalid[evt.id])
                    {
                        // async/thread pool
                        if (evt.loop)
                        {
                            event_queue.emplace(evt.next());
                        }

                        std::async(std::launch::async, [evt]() { evt(); });
                    }

                    event_queue.pop();
                }

                std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(10));
            }
        });
    }
    ~Timer() { stop(); if (handler) { handler->join(); } }

    int add(const callback_type & cb, const time_type & when, const msec_type & duration = msec_type(0), int times = 0)
    {
        auto id = ++taskid;

        if (times > 0)
        {
            timer_event task{ id, cb, when, duration };
            event_queue.emplace(task);

            while (--times)
            {
                event_queue.emplace(task.next());
            }
        }
        else if (duration > msec_type(0))
        {
            event_queue.emplace(id, cb, when, duration, true);
        }
        else
        {
            event_queue.emplace(id, cb, when);
        }

        return id;
    }
    void del(int id) { invalid[id] = true; }
    void stop() { _stop = true; }
};
}
```

**timer_test.cpp**

```
#include "timer.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;
static auto now = system_clock::now();

void foo()
{
    std::cout << (duration<double>(system_clock::now() - now)).count() << "s => func foo" << std::endl;
}

void done()
{
    std::cout << "> " << (duration<double>(system_clock::now() - now)).count() << "s => Done!" << std::endl;
}

struct bar
{
    void hello()
    {
        std::cout << (duration<double>(system_clock::now() - now)).count() << "s => func bar::hello" << std::endl;
    }
};

int test_loop_timer()
{
    easy::Timer g_timer;
    g_timer.add([ = ]()
    {
        easy::Timer timer;
        bar b;
        std::vector<int> taskids;
        auto curr = system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "> timer " << ": " << (duration<double>(curr - now)).count() << "s => Start!" << std::endl;
        taskids.push_back(timer.add(foo, curr + seconds(2)));
        taskids.push_back(timer.add(std::bind(&bar::hello, b), curr + seconds(3), seconds(3), 3));
        taskids.push_back(timer.add(
        [ = ]() { std::cout << (duration<double>(system_clock::now() - now)).count() << "s => func lambda" << std::endl; },
        curr + seconds(4), seconds(2)));
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(10));

        for (auto id : taskids)
        {
            std::cout << "> timer " << ": del " << id << std::endl;
            timer.del(id);
        }

        timer.stop();
        curr = system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "> timer " << ": " << (duration<double>(curr - now)).count() << "s => Stop!" << std::endl;
    },
    system_clock::now() + seconds(4), seconds(15));
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(60));
    return 0;
}
int test_timer()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> timers;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        timers.emplace_back([i]()
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(12 * i));
            easy::Timer timer;
            bar b;
            std::vector<int> taskids;
            auto curr = system_clock::now();
            std::cout << "> timer " << i << ": " << (duration<double>(curr - now)).count() << "s => Start!" << std::endl;
            taskids.push_back(timer.add(foo, curr + seconds(2)));
            taskids.push_back(timer.add(std::bind(&bar::hello, b), curr + seconds(3), seconds(3), 3));
            taskids.push_back(timer.add(
            [ = ]() { std::cout << (duration<double>(system_clock::now() - now)).count() << "s => func lambda" << std::endl; },
            curr + seconds(4), seconds(2)));
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(seconds(10));

            for (auto id : taskids)
            {
                std::cout << "> timer " << i << ": del " << id << std::endl;
                timer.del(id);
            }

            timer.stop();
            curr = system_clock::now();
            std::cout << "> timer " << i << ": " << (duration<double>(curr - now)).count() << "s => Stop!" << std::endl;
        });
    }

    for (auto & th : timers)
    {
        th.join();
    }

    done();
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    test_loop_timer();
    //test_timer();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! It seems like the header will need to link to `pthread` on linux, and I believe having a header only library with link dependencies is not a good idea in general. I've dealt with some of those, and without proper CMake it is quite hard to deal with, although this case is very simple.

Comment: I use visual studio to compile this code. I supposed that std::thread should be implemented above platforms. On msys2  Mingw64, this code compiled by g++, but not work!?

Answer (score 1):

## Race conditions

- Accesses to `Timer::event_queue` and `Timer::invalid` aren't synchronized. Maybe add a `std::mutex` and lock it to synchronize accesses?

## Implementation

- `Timer::invalid` could be a `std::unordered_map<int, bool>`. This would reduce lookup and insertion time complexity to \$O(1)\$ (down from \$O(\log n)\$).
- Entries in `Timer::invalid` never get erased. This means that in a long running program where new events are added frequently it will claim more and more memory. Even worse, `if(!invalid[evt.id])` creates a new entry in `invalid` if `invalid[evt.id]` doesn't already exist.
- `start` in the `Timer::handler` thread routine is never used.
- Many member functions of `Timer`, `timer_event` and `event_less` could be marked `const` and/or `noexcept`.
- Parameters `id` and `loop` of the first `timer_event`constructor, parameter `id` of `Timer::del` and `now` in the `Timer::handler` thread routine can be marked `const`.

Comment: `Timer::invalid` always increases, I supposed this timer only lives one day, only one lives every day.